# Access VBA DoCmd.TransferText CSV Import - False datatype detection removing necessary string info

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, import, sqldatatypes

Importing a CSV file into Access through VBA with `DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim` which works fine, however I have a required field in the CSV file that will contain values such as "2024061.023.1733.1937" which I would like to import as Short Text, but it auto imports as currency. So it therefore drops everything after the first "." section and shows $2,024,061.023 in the table.

I have tried to find an answer and have found some ways such as transfer the data to a new table that already has fields set as Short Text which i started to implement, however from the initially imported data the main required field has already lost the ".1733.1937" part of the string which I need.

Wondering if anyone has a work around for this.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
On Error Resume Next:   db.TableDefs.Delete "tblImport":   On Error GoTo Err_Field_Import
db.TableDefs.Refresh
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="tblImport", _
    FileName:="results.csv", HasFieldNames:=True
db.TableDefs.Refresh
```

For my testing, results.csv just looks like below, but ultimately it will contain about 72 columns of various Datatypes, this Project field is just the most important to get right.

```
Project
20245061.023.1733.1937
```

Edit: Manual link is possible, but having VBA do it from a button click within a form, to fill in some of the form info simplifies the process for the non tech savvy users. This importing will also happen daily or multiple times a day so having VBA do it is easier on their part.

Comment: What do you mean by "however from the initially imported data the main required field has already lost" - import to existing table is still dropping characters? Perhaps you should build an import specification. Do that by manually executing the import with External Data wizard and saving. Why do you need VBA to set link? Why is this a repetitive process? Why not just manually set the link once and be done?

Comment: @June7 That was mainly an aside about making it Short Text from Currency, but since it got auto typed as Currency upon import, the last portion is immediately removed which makes any Currency to Text conversion pointless. Also using VBA as I just want a single button solution for the main users who will have to use it. I've been playing around for a bit though and seems using TransferSpreadsheet instead of TransferText is working exactly as I need so I will just use that.

Comment: Still not clear to me why you need to program this linking. Could write an answer to your own question and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could find, defining field datatypes isn't possible using `DoCmd.TransferText`. The data I was getting from a separate source had the option to be exported as CSV or Excel, so I ended up trying the Excel export option and then importing into access through `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` and it worked flawlessly as it used the datatype of the excel fields. So this is the solution I'm going to go with.